# Какие есть структуры данных?Рекурсия

Tags: c++, структуры, структуры-данных

Есть только два вида структур? линейные и не линейние?? А рекурсивные стуркутуры это как третий вид или это подвид линейных? Или как лучше клисифицировать структуры данных?

Одна переменная это тоже структура?

Comment: Структура (и вообще любое данное или набор данных) не может быть рекурсивной. Рекурсивным может быть только действие - например, процедура обхода элементов структуры.

Comment: в интернете вы можете найти и прочитать ответы на подобные вопросы - прогуглите